# Regex to get first part of a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this regex

```
(?<=\d\.\s).+(?=\s-\s)
```

It works great when I have a string like

```
3. product - sub product
```

The regex gives me the product (first part). If a sub-product exists it is delimited from the product by a dash surrounded with spaces (`-`).

However, there are some products which do not have sub-product. For example:

```
6. ComprehensiveBolt
```

The regex should give me `comprehensiveBolt` but it does not return anything.

What update do I need to make to my regex so I can get the product  regardless of the presence, or otherwise, of a sub-product?

Comment: `?` means optional. You can use that.

Comment: can you put the full syntax here. I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You are using `(?=\s-\s)` to _qualify_ the product. If you make it _optional_ `(?=\s-\s)?` it will never have to match the assertion, and it most probably won't. The better approach is to use boundary's or whitespace indicators. You could try `(?<=\d\.\s).+?(?=\s-\s)?` but you must make the `.+` non-greedy either way.

Comment: If the product name always consists of just upper and lower case letters, you can just do something simpler such as this https://regex101.com/r/1w2gxA/2

Comment: @sln : it only highlights the first letter

Comment: @CAustin: Looks like its working on the web but when I copied it to my local window I am getting Unrecognized escape sequence \K

Comment: @sln: works. thanks. can you reply as answer so i can mark it complete.

Comment: I put it into the answer pile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way.
Note this is only needed if your product could be a phrase.

`(?<=\d\.\s)(?:(?!\s-\s|\d\.\s).)+`

https://regex101.com/r/uC2yDs/1

Partial explanation

```
 (?<= \d \. \s )               # This must be behind
 (?:                           # -----------
      (?!                           # Neg assertion
           \s - \s                       # Not this ahead
        |  \d \. \s                      # Nor this ahead
      )
      .                             # Ok, grab this character
 )+                            #  1 to many times
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked in first try. Thanks sln